# Choose launchSettings.json profile based on build configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I need to choose profile from launchSettings.json based on chosen build config. Lets say I have build config Debug, Debug-2 and I need to choose different profile for each of them from launchSettings.json. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the launch profile selector dropdown for the run button?

Comment: Yes, there is. We use remote debugging therefore, when you choose build configuration there is a remote debug machine for every config and there is pre-build step that does some copying and needs the remote debug machine name. It is just one more step, that you need to remember to do, so It is not very practical.

Comment: Another reason could be that you launch multiple projects where you dont get the profile selector.

Answer (score 3):

I use "Copy" MSBuild task to override launchSettings.json with either Debug or Release versions during the build:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Include="Properties/launchSettings.$(Configuration).json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CleanLaunchSettings" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Deleting launchSettings.json..." />
    <Delete Files="Properties/launchSettings.json" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CopyLaunchSettings" AfterTargets="Build" Inputs="Properties/launchSettings.$(Configuration).json" Outputs="Properties/launchSettings.json">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Copying launchSettings.$(Configuration).json..." />
    <Copy SourceFiles="Properties/launchSettings.$(Configuration).json" DestinationFiles="Properties/launchSettings.json" />
  </Target>
```